# .htaccess Get requests in the URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I don't know how I would word this, and I can't make sense of the docs for httpd so I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this.

I would like to get

> www.example.com/v/12345/yadayada.png

to actually go to

> www.example.com/view?key=12345&img=yadayada.png

I've seen this done some websites but I cant find out how to do this.

Thanks

Edit 1:

I tried this, and then entered the following URL:

> www.example.com/v/3f210a2c76cb100f4f7fbd7691a9eb967cb7a1a7/10b78802581bfd59f3fe2b447575bdf7.png

When I did this I got the following error:

> The requested URL /v/3f210a2c76cb100f4f7fbd7691a9eb967cb7a1a7/10b78802581bfd59f3fe2b447575bdf7.png was not found on this server.

This is my current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^./]+\.png)$ /i/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^v/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+\.(png|jpe?g|gif))$ /view.php?k=$1&img=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JonLin had the right rule, but the rewrite rule you have declared before that one,

```
RewriteRule ^([^./]+\.png)$ /i/$1 [L,NC]
```

is applied to the example url you provided. So, with a request like

```
www.example.com/v/3f210/10b7.png
```

would get rewritten to

```
www.example.com/i/v/3f210/10b7.png
```

It's worth noting the Flags used for your rules

```
L - Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules
NC - Makes the pattern comparison case-insensitive.
```

If you were to remove that rule you would get the results you want. You should also determine if that rule is needed and modify it, the flags, and/or rearrange the order of your rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v/([0-9]+)/([^/.]+\.(png|jpe?g|gif))$ /view.php?k=$1&img=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v/([0-9a-f]+)/([^/.]+\.(png|jpe?g|gif))$ /view?key=$1&img=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Edited Post to add in (Formatting)

Comment: @user2619443 It wasn't clear that the "key" part could also contain letters, see the edit above